# Can you loop through different model inputs in R?

Tags: r, lme4

My problem is this, I want to test out different combinations of fixed and random effects for my mixed model and record the model evaluation metric each time to determine which is the best combination of features.

For instance with the dataset **Fruit** that has the following features:

- taste
- smell
- tree
- farm
- soldStatus

In code it looks like this with lmer() in R:

```
mod1 = lmer(soldStatus ~ smell + (1|farm), Fruit)
mod2 = lmer(soldStatus ~ taste + (1|farm), Fruit)
mod3 = lmer(soldStatus ~ smell + (1|tree), Fruit)
mod4 = lmer(soldStatus ~ taste + (1|tree), Fruit)
mod5 = lmer(soldStatus ~ smell+taste + (1|farm), Fruit)
mod6 = lmer(soldStatus ~ smell+taste + (1|tree), Fruit)
```

With my real data set I can not manually type all the models as there are about 60 fixed variables and 10 random.

Is there a way I can automate this process in R? Potentially also add in combinations of random effects as well such as this:

```
mod6 = lmer(soldStatus ~ smell+taste + (1|tree) + (1|farm), Fruit)
mod7 = lmer(soldStatus ~ smell + (1|tree) + (1|farm), Fruit)
mod8 = lmer(soldStatus ~ taste + (1|tree) + (1|farm), Fruit)
```

Comment: How many variables do you want to have in your formula at one time? The problem is that even if you *only* wanted a combination of two fixed and two random effects in each model tested, given you have 60 fixed and 10  random variables, you would have to run `lmer` 79,650 times. Then you have the problem of type 1 errors: even if there was no real correlation you would get 4000 "significant" results. I wonder if you need to try a different approach to your problem?

Comment: @AllanCameron, I was thinking I should maybe perform feature selection and hopefully that reduces the amount of features. But I am not sure if this would be a bad thing to do as the feature selection may use a non mixed effects model but instead like a tree. Would this be a good idea, or what other approaches would you suggests for this problem?

Comment: I agree with Allan Cameron. Check for example the discussion in this link: https://www.researchgate.net/post/How-to-identify-the-relative-importance-of-each-variable-in-linear-mixed-model about how to check the importance of feature. good luck!

Comment: The [glmulti package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=glmulti) will do this kind of exhaustive search, but not for random effects models. `MuMIn::dredge()` will try to do an exhaustive search (but you probably don't want to fit 80K models, and it doesn't select among random effects).  You might try `glmmLasso` ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker Thank you, glmmLasso looks like it would work as well along side taking into account Allan's advice.

Comment: If you come up with a solution based on the suggestions in the comments, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not the exact solution I wanted but I just ended up using the drop1() function. As glmmLasso for didn't work for my model and took a really long time.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.